# Using TADOQuery result in another query?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, csv, ado

Using Delphi 2009. I have a TADOConnection to folder containing a csv file and a TADOQuery that pulls data from a csv file in there (Call it TADOQueryCSV). That works OK.

I also have a second TADOConnection to an Access database with a table called AccessTbl_TEMP and various TADOQueries that process data in there. They work OK.

Now I want to process the data returned by the TADOQueryCSV and insert it into the table in the Access database. But how do I refer to the data returned from the csv file.?

I need something like this but don't know how to write the FROM clause.

INSERT INTO AccessTbl_TEMP ( Field1,Field2 )
SELECT csvField1, csvField2
FROM
TADOQueryCSV;

Answer (score 2):

You can move the data in code in Delphi. dsSource is TADOQueryCSV and dsTarget is the table AccessTbl_TEMP.

```
dsSource.First;
while not dsSource.Eof do
begin
    dsTarget.Append;
    // Assign field values from dsSource to dsTarget
    dsTarget.Post;
    dsSource.Next;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the MS Access linked tables, where a linked table will point to a CSV file.

Comment: Thats what I do at the moment. I was trying to get away from the hassel of MSAccess table linking (especially when installed on the customers machines) and do it all in delphi, leaving the access database just as a database. Also soon I want to drop access and use firebird or something better so need delphi to do the processing.

Comment: Then you can move data into a temporary table and then use it content in queries. But that will slow down the full operation.

Comment: You can include a connect string in the FROM clause with the IN operator. The exact syntax will depend on your particulars, but what I always do is create a linked table, then take the resulting connect string and then use the query designer, and paste the connect string parts into the two relevant query properties, Source Database and Source Connect String.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is faster way :

```
for x := 0 to Source.fieldcount - 1 do
begin
Target.fieldbyname(Source.fields[x].fieldname).value :=
Source.fields[x].value;
except
end;
end;
```

using value will convert the data for you.
using the try / except concept will keep you from having to determine if
the field is there